# Macros conditional compiling not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

I am checking iOS version in the following way

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

Now I want to compile a class on basis of this

```
#if defined SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0")
    #import "SomeClassBelowiOS9.h"
#else
    #import "SomeClassIniOS9AndAbove.h"
#endif
```

I get an error **Token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression**

**EDIT:**

It works like this but I am not sure If this is a good solution, basic idea is to reuse a macro in a simpler way

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define belowiOS9 SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0")

#if belowiOS9
    #import "SomeClassBelowiOS9.h"
#else
    #import "SomeClassIniOS9AndAbove.h"
#endif
```

Comment: You seem confused between the difference of compile-time and runtime.

Comment: Have a look at `NSFoundationVersionNumber` constant. Maybe it would be better solution for you.

Comment: @trojanfoe what you mean is, so we can't import headers based on already defined macros?

Comment: No of course you can, but think about what that macro is expanding to.  It can only be evaluated at runtime, not compile time and so cannot affect which file is included as you trying to make it.  It looks to me like you want the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` if you are attempting to include different classes depending on your deployment target.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks how #define belowiOS9 SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0") is evaluated at compile time. Secondly whats better  #define belowiOS9 SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0") or #define belowiOS9 
__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 90000

Comment: Well have a think.  What is the machine you are compiling this code on?  A Mac right.  Now `UIDevice` is an iOS class and it's designed to be used within an iOS app.  Have a search for `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED ` to see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> The Objective-C Preprocessor is not part of the compiler, but is a
>   separate step in the compilation process. In simplistic terms, an
>   Objective-C Preprocessor is just a text substitution tool and it
>   instructs compiler to do required pre-processing before actual
>   compilation

Maybe you are get error in a line which is pre-processing condition.

```
#if defined SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0")
```

`#if` need to be evaluated at compile-time. But`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` just has value at run-time. That why the compiler can't compile this line.

As @trojacfoe said, try with `#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`

Comment: "So it can't be placed in the macro" isn't true.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry. I'm wrong. I usually using static func for these issue in a wrapper. Thank you very much.